# Method to add a class to an array keeps adding the classes to the first position only

Tags: java

Here is the method

```
public void addModuleToStudent(Module aModule)
 {
    int position = 0; 
    if(position > 3)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: Student already has four modules\n");
    }
    else
    {
        moduleArray[position] = aModule;
        position++;
    }
 }
```

The problem is that the position doesn't seem to be increment the position variable because when ever I add a module class it occupies the 1st position in the the array and when I add another instead of being added into the second position it overwrites the first.

Comment: Because you initialise `position` to 0 every time you enter the method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `position` is a local variable. Every time you call `addModuleToStudent`, you get a new variable, initialized as 0.

It sounds like you want to make this an *instance* variable instead, so that it persists between method calls.

Better yet, don't use an array instead - use an `ArrayList<Module>` instead, and then you can just use:

```
public void addModuleToStudent(Module module)
{
    if (modules.size() > 3)
    {
        throw new SomeAppropriateException("Cannot have more than 4 modules");
    }
    modules.add(module);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`position` is a local variable, each time you call your `addModuleToStudent` method it is re-initialized to `zero`. So, do something like

```
int position=0
public void addModuleToStudent(Module aModule)
{
  //your logic here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're resetting `position` to zero *every time the method is called*

Either make `position` an instance variable in the class, or use a `Vector<Module>` or an `ArrayList<Module>` instead of an array and call:

```
modules.add(aModules);
```

to add each new module onto the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are calling the `addModuleToStudent` method each time and that you want to add a module and that `moduleArray` is some global variable...

The problem here is that whenever you call the method, `position` is always initialized to 0. To solve your problem, what you might want to do is to remove the `int position = 0;` line and use the `position` variable as a global variable.